# 「なでさすられて」の文法は何ですか。

Tags: grammar

「なでさすられて」 の文法を詳しく説明していただけませんか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、「撫{な}で摩{さす}る」ですが、これは複合動詞です。ふたつの動詞が結合してひとつの動詞として機能します。「撫でて摩る」("to stroke & rub") という意味になります。

「られて」は「られる」のテ形で、**受け身**を表します。Passive voice です。

従って、「なでさすられて」は他の人に「なでられて、（そして）さすられて」という意味になります。英語で確認しておきますと、"to be stroked and rubbed" です。

文法的には、「受け身」または「受動態」と呼ばれています。